# Need help on importing QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I need some help on QML importing. I have 2 projects, name Project1 and Project2

```
Project 1
|-QmlFile1.qml
|-qml1.qrc

Project 2
|-QmlFile2.qml
|-qml2.qrc
```

Is it possible to import QmlFile1.qml from Project 1 to QmlFile2.qml of Project 2?
**QT_WS\TestQuick\main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "../COMMON"
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyButton {
        id: button1
    }
}
```

**QT_WS\COMMON\MyButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 80
    Rectangle {
        id: button
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

**QT_WS\TestQuick\TestQuick.pro**

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    sharedresource.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**main.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**sharedresource.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>../COMMON/MyButton.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**Error:**

```
Starting C:\Personal\QT_WS\build-TestQuick-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\TestQuick.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3 "../COMMON": no such directory

C:/Personal/QT_WS/build-TestQuick-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/TestQuick.exe exited with code -1
```

[Folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAbqf.png)

Comment: Have you tried it? You can import any qml file as long as you tell it where to find it.

Comment: I tried something like this. in QmlFile2.qml
import "../Project1/"
QmlFile1 {
}

Thing is in Qt Creator QmlFile1 is getting resolved. But while execution, I am getting error, like 
../Project1": no such directory

Comment: QML files under same project folder in any sub-directory, working fine. But not sure where I am going wrong here. New to QML development. So not able to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're probably missing is the qml file is not in your .qrc file so it doesn't know where to find it. If you're going to be sharing code between projects, it makes sense to create a separate .qrc file for common files that will be included in both. So your project structure could look like this:

```
Project 1
  |---qml1.qrc        // Files for Project1
      |---someFile1.qml
  |---shared_qml.qrc  // Shared files
      |---sharedFile1.qml
      |---sharedFile2.qml

Project 2
  |---qml2.qrc        // Files for Project2
      |---someFile2.qml
  |---shared_qml.qrc  // Shared files
      |---sharedFile1.qml
      |---sharedFile2.qml
```

EDIT:

I tried building a project with the same structure you used. It worked when I imported the file like this:

```
import "qrc:/../COMMON"
```

Comment: Hi @JarMan.. Thanks for your replay. This commenting /answering here is very confusing for me ;-) . Added an answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Could you provide your actual directory structure and your actual .pro and .qrc files? This is why a minimal reproducible example is always needed.

Comment: Also added a screenshot for the folder structure

Comment: Could you add your .qrc files? And I need to see your actual directory structure, not the QtCreator project structure. EDIT: Oh, I see the paths in your filenames.

Comment: Added resource files also

Comment: Excellent!!!... Thank you very much @JarMan. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to share code in the way you are trying to do it now, as the qrc system does not support pointing to paths outside the project tree.

Instead, I would suggest you factor out the shared code into a library that you then use from both projects. That  will probably be easier to maintain in the long run anyway.

Comment: Thanks @André  for the information. I will give a try. I think this only way left right now for me :)